# Fast Constrained Least Squares

Tags: python, r, performance, matlab, optimization

I have to solve many independent constrained linear least squares problems (with both bounds and constrains). So I do it multiple times in loops. For each problem I am looking for x that is min||Cx-d|| and x is bounded (in 0,1) and all x elements must sum to 1.

I am seeking a way of doing it fast, because although each optimization doesn't require a lot of time, I need to include it in a large loop.

For example my Matlab implementation seems like this:

```
img = imread('test.tif');
C = randi(255,6,4);
x=zeros(size(C,2),1);
tp = zeros(size(C,2),1); 

Aeq = ones(1,size(C,2));
beq = 1;
options = optimset('LargeScale','off','Display','off'); 
A = (-1).*eye(size(C,2)); 
b = zeros(1,size(C,2)); 
result = zeros(size(img,1),size(img,2),size(C,2));
for i=1:size(img,1)
    for j=1:size(img,2)
        for k=1:size(img,3)
            tp(k) = img(i,j,k);
        end
        x = lsqlin(C,tp,A,b,Aeq,beq,[],[],[],options);
        for l=1:size(C,2)
            result(i,j,l)=x(l); 
        end      
    end
end
```

and for a 500x500 loop it takes about 5 minutes. But my loops are much bigger than this. Any idea is welcome, but I would prefer a Matlab, Python or R solution.

Comment: NumPy is probably a good place to start. It writes like MATLAB and it's faster than looping

Comment: I have tried the [SciPy minimize function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) as well, but not much difference from Matlab [lsqlin](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html), but that's not what you mean probably, right?

Comment: I suggest to add a description of what this code does for those that don't speak Matlab.

Comment: In general, with higher level languages such as MATLAB, or Python, it is preferable to use implied loops instead of explicit loops whenever possible. This is because the implied loop methods are usually implemented in a lower level (read faster) language.

Comment: Matlab's `lsqlin`, R's `limSolve::lsei` (implemented in FORTRAN) and whatever python uses must all be pretty close... I feel you are just asking to solve too many problems and need to rethink your overall problem. Can you tell us a little more?

Comment: You will not get a significant speed-up with your approach. These functions tend to be highly optimized in all languages, and in fact they often interface with the same linear algebra libraries to solve it. The only way to get a major speed boost is to take advantage some additional information/insight about your *specific* problem, so you need to give us some specifics.

Comment: If the problems are close to one another, 
you can specify the last solution found as a starting point `x0`:
that should speed up the optimizations.
You can also try to run the computations in parallel, if Matlab allows it.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd unfortunately, problems are independent, so I cannot use better x0 and at the moment I don't have a cluster available for parallel processing, but that seems a good alternative to think of.

Comment: @Bitwise I edited the post, by I don't know if more details will be helpful or more confusing. The problem is relatively simple, with small matrices involved. I want to use it for [Spectral Unmixing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaging_spectroscopy#Unmixing) in image data, so I need to solve the problem for every pixel that is why I have the loop.

Comment: @user2606048 How about caching results so if pixel value is equal (or very close) you don't have to recalculate the solution?

Comment: @user2606048 Also, you can try tweaking algorithm parameters. For example, since these algorithms perform iterations until they reach a threshold, you can raise the threshold to trade off accuracy for speed.

Comment: @sihrc Though it may be true that MATLAB can be beaten at looping, this is not going have a significant impact if a loop of 500x500 already takes 5 minutes. The loops are obviously slow because of their content.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments: The used commands are highly optimized, and switching languages is not going to make a world of difference.

First of all go back to what you are trying to achieve, perhaps to achieve that you don't need to solve this many hard problems.

If you come to the conclusion that you do want to do this exact calculation, consider changing the settings, and play around with the algorithm.

From `doc lsqlin` it appears the two main parameters that determine the speed are:

- Number of iterations
- Accepted tolerance

---

If all these things don't help enough, consider some tricks like:

- Only solving problems that are sufficiently different
- Solving with easier constraints, and rounding the result